# Why PS1 is not updated with the git branch name?

Tags: git, bash

```
PS1="\\w (`git branch | grep '^*' | cut -b 3-100`)$ "
```

I set my PS1 as above, but it will not update the branch name in the prompt after I change the branch with `git checkout`, or change the repository with the `cd`. How to fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The backtick-quoted bit is evaluated when `PS1` is set (once), not when the prompt is displayed. Use single quotes to save the expansion for the latter event:

```
PS1='\w (`git branch | grep "^*" | cut -b 3-100`)$ '
```