# Mac OS Catalina: PS1 not updating when I change branch or directory

Tags: bash, git, macos, terminal, ps1

I tried to set `PS1` in the bash_profile as,

```
.bash_profile
#!/bin/bash

# .....

parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

parse_pwd() {
  basename $PWD
}

PS1=''$(parse_pwd)''$(parse_git_branch)' $ '
```

Got the expected output: `<project-directory-name> (git-branch-name) $`

**Problem:**

When I change the branch or change project then `PS1` details are not updating (i.e. neither the branch name nor the project-directory-name). I had to manually run `source ~/.bash_profile` to see those changes in the terminal.

I googled and tried few suggestions like,

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38429139/967638
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5380026/967638

Not sure, but is it something to do with my bash? I am currently using zsh,

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
```

Comment: If you are using `zsh`, modifying the `bash` prompt won't do anything.

Comment: you can try changing your default login shell to bash. It will then start working

Comment: @Amarmath : Why are you fiddling with the bash configuration, if you don't intend to use bash? I would port your definitions over to zsh. While in zsh, the canonical way to do what you want could be made easier (for instance `$(parse_pwd)` would be better written as `$PWD:t` in zsh), at first glance I think that your functions would work in zsh as well. Just put the definitions into `.zshrc`.

Comment: Check again the first of the two SO answers, and note the difference between a backtick `\`` and a single quote `'`.

Comment: I think removing the inner single quotes in your `PS1` variable should work for you

Comment: @vikashkumar Changing default shell to **bash** solved the issue. Can you put it as answer so that I can accept the same?

Comment: @Amarnath I can see the question is closed. Anyway, the purpose of this platform is to learn by helping each other. So, it's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the prompt for Zsh:

`PROMPT="⚡️%{$fg[red]%} ☣︎☯︎⚰︎☤⚚♱♚☨☥☥☨♚♱⚚☤⚰︎☯︎☣︎ %{$fg[red]%}⚡%{$fg[green]%}%T⚡️%{$fg[green]%}%{$fg[yellow]%}%d%{$fg[yellow]%} ⚡️"`

^This is just an example of the difference between bash and zsh when setting prompt.^

for your case check this link:

https://www.themoderncoder.com/add-git-branch-information-to-your-zsh-prompt/

or change to bash using:

`chsh -s /bin/sh`

Comment: Changing to bash solved my issue. Thanks!